# Not select only first row in column

Tags: php, mysql, select

functions.php

```
function getfriendone($id, $field){
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `$field` FROM `friends` WHERE `user_one`='$id'");
$run = mysql_fetch_array($query);
return $run[$field];
}

function getfriendtwo($id, $field){
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `$field` FROM `friends` WHERE `user_two`='$id'");
$run = mysql_fetch_array($query);
return $run[$field];
}
```

index.php

```
$fetch_friends = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$two = getfriendone($fetch_friends, 'user_two');
$three = getfriendtwo($fetch_friends, 'user_one');

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id IN ('$two', '$three')");
echo $two." | ".$three;
```

Table (friends) for getfriend function

```
ID    user_one    user_two
1     1           2
2     1           3
3     4           1
```

Table (posts) for $result

```
ID    TEXT    NAME
1     Hello   Bob
1     Hello   Bob
2     Hello   Mark
```

What i wanna do here is echo all the rows that has integer 1 in it in both user_one and user_two. In my chase, only ID 1 and 3 will be echoed here. It picks the first match and echos only that one. It works as it should, but only with the first match in the column

Comment: do not use mysql_ instead use mysqli_ or pdo

Comment: mysql_query function and mysql* functions are all deprecated meaning removed from the current latest php versions. So you better use not use to avoid problems. Your code is also prone to sql injection. Just said

Answer (score 1):

If i read properly:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts s
WHERE 
EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM posts s2 WHERE s.id = s2.user_one) OR
(SELECT 1 FROM posts s2 WHERE s.id = s2.user_two)
```

Will extract the data you need

SQLFiddle -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ae070/3/0